# Missing Value Errors when heavily using Javascript in Safari by Applescript

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, applescript

Sorry for the possibly confusing title.

My problem is that I'd like to download Apple's Command Line Tools for XCode without the need to click on the single buttons. I want to use this for a faster setup of new developer workstations combined with Chef.

The script and error are as follows:

```
tell application "Safari"
    make new document at end of every document --> document "Ohne Titel"
    set URL of document 1 to "https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action"
    get name of document 1 --> "Ohne Titel"
    do JavaScript "var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
                   var script= document.createElement('script');
                   script.type= 'text/javascript';
                   script.src= 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';
                   head.appendChild(script);" in document 1 --> missing value
    do JavaScript "alert('test')" in document 1 --> missing value
    do JavaScript "document.forms['appleConnectForm']['accountname'].value = 'somename'" in document 1 --> missing value
    do JavaScript "document.forms['appleConnectForm']['accountpassword'].value = 'somepassword'" in document 1 --> missing value
    do JavaScript "document.appleConnectForm.submit();" in document 1 --> missing value
    do JavaScript "var atags = document.getElementsByTagName('a')" in document 1 --> missing value
    do JavaScript "for (var i=0; i<atags.length; i++){ if (atags.textContent=='Command Line Tools for Xcode'){ atags[i].click(); } }" in document 1 --> missing value
    set name of window 1 to "Ohne Titel"
end tell
```

Updates to the the script and errors I am running into here: https://gist.github.com/1993352

The Javascript on line 17 is properly executed and I see an alert message. Any of the other lines is not executed as expected.

How can I get this to work and is the current Javascript not executed except for this one line?

Comment: Humor me: Why not download the file to a server you own and make it accessible to the workstations via a static URL?

Comment: P.S. In AppleScript `missing value` is not an error, it's a constant, equivalent to `null` or `undefined`. It just indicates that the message (function) didn't return anything.

Comment: @Jordan Hosting it ourselves is probably the easiest way... I just wanted to ensure that it's always up to date. This might be not a big issue though as the software is not updated very often.

Comment: @MartinKlepsch: scripting works too – it’s just some minor corrections to your approach (see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

As @Jordan stated [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603288/missing-value-errors-when-heavily-using-javascript-in-safari-by-applescript#comment12182793_9603288), the `missing value` returned from `do JavaScript` does not indicate an error. However, your code suffers from a few problems that do stop it from working:

1. it does not wait for the page to load completely before trying to access the form – hence your `value` assignments and `submit()` call go into the void. You can go fancy and try to wait for a matching window name, but a simple `delay` will do;
2. it tries to inspect the text content of all found elements (`atags.textContent`) instead of the currently looped-over one (`atags[i].textContent`);
3. it tries to trigger a `click` event by calling the `click()` method, which most browsers refuse to do, ostensibly for security reasons (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10141849/990363) and [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10143157/990363)). As Apple does not include jQuery, the issue is not quite as straightforward to sidestep as in the answer I linked to – you can, however, simulate the click event with a bit of code courtesy of Protolicious’ [`event.simulate.js`](https://github.com/kangax/protolicious/blob/master/event.simulate.js).

The following code will do what you asked for:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set loadDelay to 2 -- in seconds; test for your system
    make new document at end of every document
    set URL of document 1 to "https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action"
    delay loadDelay
    do JavaScript "_connectForm = document.forms.appleConnectForm;
                   _connectForm.accountname.value = 'your_accountname';
                   _connectForm.accountpassword.value = 'your_accountpassword';
                   _connectForm.submit();" in document 1
    delay loadDelay
    do JavaScript "var _atags = document.querySelectorAll('a');
                   for (var i=0; i<_atags.length; i++){ 
                       if (_atags[i].innerText.indexOf('Command Line Tools for Xcode') === 0){ 
                           _event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
                           _event.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, document.defaultView, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, _atags[i]);
                           _atags[i].dispatchEvent(_event);
                           break;
                       }
                   }" in document 1
end tell
```

*Tested with my own account; download of most recent Xcode Command Line Tools package (to be precise – topmost listed) started successfully.*