# Clicking on JavaScript/jQuery link with Applescript

Tags: javascript, applescript

I haven't ever done much with AppleScript, but I'm trying to automate this process. I have a website with a Button that needs to be clicked. However the button is implemented with JavaScript/jQuery/AJAX like so:

```
<div id="divIdOfButton" class="someClass">
    <div class="divClassOfButton someOtherClass">
        <img src="imgOfButton">
    <div>

...

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#divIdOfButton .divClassOfButton).click(function() {
...
}}
```

I tried this without any luck

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    delay 1
    set URL of first document to "http://example.com/"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('divIdOfButton').getElementByClassName('divClassOfButton')[0].click()" in front document
end tell
```

I did a bunch of searching, but couldn't find anything. Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a site that requires a membership..

Comment: Would it work if I copied the whole $(document.ready(.... into applescript and said "do Javascript " ... " in front document?

Comment: Just covering the bases here, but you have been wrapping that `do JavaScript` statement in a `tell application "Safari"` block, yes?

Comment: Yes, I did. I added the full code above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most browsers will ignore direct calls to the click event handler, [it seems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/210643/990363) (apparently for security reasons – don’t get me started on the JavaScript security model in browsers), so your `click()` call just does nothing at all. You can trigger the click event via JavaScript’s event dispatching mechanism (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603288/missing-value-errors-when-heavily-using-javascript-in-safari-by-applescript) and [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10145332/990363)). However, if the site you target already does include jQuery, all you need to do is:

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "$('#divIdOfButton .divClassOfButton').click();" in front document
end tell
```

If there are several buttons of the class in your `DIV`, you’ll need to add a filter expression, i.e.

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "$('#divIdOfButton .divClassOfButton :equ(0)).click();" in front document
end tell
```

but you will lose the performance advantage of `querySelectorAll` leveraged by jQuery without this (see [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)).

*Tested by triggering the inbox dropdown on Stack Overflow sites in Safari.*

Comment: The statement `You cannot trigger the click event from plain JavaScript` is incorrect (and contradicted by your link). You can use *dispatchEvent* (W3C compliant) or *fireEvent* (IE compatible) as appropriate, or if the browser supports HTML5, call the [click method](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#dom-click) (e.g. `element.click()`). The behaviour is not particularly consistent (e.g. some versions of Firefox will not follow synthetic clicks on links), but if the OP is only concerned about a particular browser, it may be fine.

Comment: @RobG true, the sentence is not exact enough – “you cannot call the click handler directly in plain JavaScript in most browsers” would be closer to the mark (edited as such). As to HTML5 support (re-)instating this ability, however, this seems untrue at least of current versions of Safari on OS X, which in my experimentation  ignored direct calls to the click handler.

Comment: Added another iteration on the introductory sentence in the hope of achieving more precise semantics. Also added a reference to the click event dispatch approach (aka *simulate.js*).

Comment: do JavaScript only works in Safari. If you need to do something javascript inside Google Chrome, this works:

`tell application "Google Chrome"
 activate
 execute front window's active tab javascript "if (window.console) console.log( 'hi' );"
end tell`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Applescript user, but I can tell you right away that `getElementByClassName` should be `getElementsByClassName` - "elements" in the plural.

Comment: Anyway, on a reasonably current browser, you’d be much better off using [`querySelectorAll`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/), which is blazing fast and uses CSS selector strings *à la* jQuery. But that is not the issue – see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10143157/990363) for details.

Comment: Agree with kopischke there - especially since `querySelector[All]` is supported in more browsers than `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: this is a comment not an answer