# AppleScript to click a link

Tags: web, click, applescript

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <hr>
        <div id="a1">
            <div id="a2">
                <div id="a3">
                    <div class="hello">
                      <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

The webpage is like above, and I cannot find any way to click it using AppleScript. I'm very new to AppleScript. I've searched Google, but none of them is working for above.

Comment: view this one ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141849/clicking-on-javascript-jquery-link-with-applescript

Comment: Thanks, but somehow, it doesn't work for me. I've tried a few times more, but no luck so far.

Comment: Also, the example I have doesn't contain any class/id for the javascript. I could I access the <a> tag if it doesn't have any class/id?

Comment: Also, the link shows an example if the website uses jQuery, but the above example I have doesn't.

Comment: Can you add some more context for what you are trying to do? Does the click need to take place in Safari, or would a headless browser like PhantomJS work? Do you just need to issue the click, or do you need to take further action after the click? What does your existing AppleScript look like?

Comment: Yes, I should upload the AppleScript I use. There was bug in my script, and below answer gave me the hint. Next time, I will upload my trial as well. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell current tab of window 1
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('hello')[0].firstElementChild.click()"
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you. There was missing 's' when I use getElementsByClassName. Now, it's working with your answer. Thanks again.