# Do JavaScript in AppleScript works on Safari but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, applescript

I have a little AppleScript with embedded Javascript that works fine on Safari, but not on Chrome.

The Safari version(non relevant portions deleted):

```
    tell application "Safari"
    activate
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('files[]')[0].click();" in document 1 
    end tell
```

The Chrome version:

```
    tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate

    tell window 1 to tell tab 1

        execute  javascript "document.getElementsByName('files[]')[0].click();"

    end tell
```

The chrome version returns "missing value" in Apple ScriptEditor.

I CAN get other javascript commands to work and I can get

```
document.getElementsByName('files[]')[0].click();
```

or

```
document.getElementsByName("files[]")[0].click();"
```

in the Chrome console when on the proper webpage (thought it may have something to do with double quotes - still could be I suppose).

Here is the element in question:

```
<h3>Add new documents for this patient
         <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
        <span class="btn fileinput-button" style="float: right !important;">
            <span>Select Files to Upload</span>
            <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="">
        </span>
    </h3>
```

Any ideas? I have tried so many iterations of this.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn fileinput-button')[0].children[1].click();
```

works in the console, but not when in AppleScript. Seems like AppleScript weirdness to me, but...

Added information:

I can get a "click" on the logon page, so it isn't a site wide issue...

```
tell window 1 to tell tab 1

            execute javascript "document.getElementById('username').value='someLoser';"
            execute javascript "document.getElementById('password').value='YouWish'"
            execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-md btn-primary')[0].click();"

        end tell
```

works fine embedded in AppleScript.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to a security issue preventing the browser from executing the click event remotely.  I was able to perform a click with jQuery and vanilla from the console in a quick test I setup, but I was unable to execute that from an AppleScript.  I got no error and it just nothing.

I found multiple similar scenarios in other questions:

- [Clicking on JavaScript/jQuery link with Applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141849/clicking-on-javascript-jquery-link-with-applescript)
- [In JavaScript can I make a "click" event fire programmatically for a file input element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input)